# Visualforce sObject error

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two custom objects, Package__c and Product__c, I'm trying to create a form that will take input for fields of both objects on a single visualforce page and Save the data accordingly. Here is my Visualforce page -

```
    <apex:page controller="RedirectedController">
    <apex:form > 

    <apex:pageBlock >
        
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                
            <apex:inputField label="Name" value="{!objectpkg.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Account" value="{!objectpkg.Account__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Type" value="{!objectpkg.Package_Type__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Cost Of Goods" value="{!objectpkg.Cost_of_Goods_Sold__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Quantity Of Goods" value="{!objectpkg.Quantity_of_Goods_Sold__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Ready to Ship" value="{!objectpkg.Ready_to_Ship__c}"/>
                
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!saveAll}" value="Save"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>

   <apex:inputField label="Family" value="{!objectprod.Product_Family__c}"/>
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Apex Code

```
public with sharing class RedirectedController 
{
    public List<Package__c> objectpkg {get; set;}
    public List<Product__c> objectprod {get; set;}
    public Package__c pkg {get; set;}
    public Product__c prod {get; set;}
    public RedirectedController() 
    {
        List<Package__c> objectpkg = new List<Package__c>();
        List<Product__c> objectprod = new List<Product__c>();
        objectpkg = [SELECT Account__c, Cost_of_Goods_Sold__c, Name, Package_Type__c, Quantity_of_Goods_Sold__c, Ready_to_Ship__c FROM Package__c];
        objectprod =[SELECT Product_Family__c From Product__c];

    }

    public void saveAll()
    {
        insert objectpkg;
        insert objectprod;
    }

}
```

I get the error as "Could not resolve the entity from apex:inputField value binding '{!objectpkg.Name}'.  apex:inputField can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are expecting only a single Product__c and Package__c for the VF form

so, use singleton properties in the controller and resolve the queries to a single record

```
public with sharing class RedirectedController 
{
    public Package__c objectpkg {get; set;}
    public Product__c objectprod {get; set;}

   public Package__c pkg {get; set;}
   public Product__c prod {get; set;} 

    public RedirectedController() 
    {

        objectpkg = [SELECT Account__c, Cost_of_Goods_Sold__c, Name, Package_Type__c, Quantity_of_Goods_Sold__c, Ready_to_Ship__c 
                      FROM Package__c][0];
        objectprod =[SELECT Product_Family__c From Product__c][0];

    }

    public void saveAll()
    {
        insert objectpkg;
        insert objectprod;
    }

}
```

It is not clear from your VF form where the values of variables `Product__c` and `Package__c` come from -- these are sobjects and have to be queried for from some ID field made available to the controller in a URL parameter

Answer (score 1):

`objectprod` is a `List<Product__c>` so you cannot get the field from a list.

You need to iterate and then use it.

Comment: Could you post the Code ? I'm new to Salesforce so it would be helpful

Comment: You can google it, tons of example out there. Google it and you will learn faster. For eg: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm

Comment: I tried `<apex:repeat value="{!objectpkg}" var="o"> <apex:inputField label="Name" value="{!o.Name}"/> <apex:inputField label="Account" value="{!o.Account__c}"/> </apex:repeat>` and so on, now I'm not getting any errors but the inputfields are not showing up on the page

Comment: `Account__c` is a Id so it will act as a lookup. but it will show in the UI. There might be some error in your code.